# bash 'trap' not working under screen

Tags: bash

Is there a way to make `trap <cmd> EXIT` work when then bash script was started under `screen`?

Consider the simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
onexit () {
  echo 'I is ded.'
}
trap onexit EXIT
sleep 30
```

If started under a normal bash session and if I press Ctrl+C, then the trap is executed.

If I start `screen` first, then execute the above bash script and then press Ctrl+C, the trap is not executed. However, I see the 'I is ded.' string show after exiting the screen session.

I did read the man about trap not executing if the script is waiting for a command, but I wasn't expecting screen to mess with it.

Comment: Did you try the equivalent combination when using `screen` to close the session? `Control-a k`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. It works as expected when I run it in a GNU screen window.